# How to get current/compiled schema with AJV?

Tags: javascript, ajv

This question pertains to [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv).

How can I get the schema being validated?

e.g.

```
const validatePromise = ajv.compileAsync({...options.schema, $async: true});

validatePromise.then(validate => {
    validate(value).then(() => {
        // validation was successful
    }, errResult => {
        if(errResult instanceof Ajv.ValidationError) {
            // how to get the schema?
        }
    })
});
```

Before you tell me to just put `{...options.schema, $async: true}` into a variable, remember that remote schemas can be [loaded](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#asynchronous-schema-compilation) -- I want the fully-resolved schema with all of its rules and properties. Presumably all of the subschemas have loaded before `errResult` can be computed -- so where is it stored and how do I access it?

Answer (score 3):

The current schema object is in validate.schema. Ajv never constructs fully resolved schema, see [FAQ](https://ajv.js.org/faq.html#generating-schemas-with-resolved-references-ref) for the comments.